# Fluter app colors changed after compiling on Android SDK 34

Tags: flutter

After compiling my project on Android 34, the default colors of my App changed, for example the TextField became purple and before it was blue. Also, I can't switch via ThemeData.

Does anyone know why?

[image]

```
ThemeData theme = ThemeData(
  // Defina a cor primária do seu tema
  primaryColor: Colors.blue,
  // Defina a cor do texto dos botões
  buttonTheme: const ButtonThemeData(
    textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
  ),
  // Defina a cor de fundo do input
  inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white,
  ),
);

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: const MyHome(),
        theme: theme,
      ),
    );

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page')),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: const TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Teste de cor',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: By default, Material 3 is set to true. Just change it to false. otherwise change colorScheme color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on Flutter SDK version too.
Starting from Flutter SDK v3.16, Material 3 is by default set to true.

You should set it using

> useMaterial3:false

if it changed your whole app UI colors.

Meanwhile, you can also explore using **colorSchemeSeed** property.
You need to supply a color value to it and remove **primaryColor** property, both properties shouldn't be used simultaneously if you're using material 3 features.